# Oracle on Docker with pre-pumped Data

Tags: oracle, docker

I am using the following base docker file:

https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g/blob/master/Dockerfile

I read a bit on how to setup a data Volumne from this [SO question](http://www.offermann.us/2013/12/tiny-docker-pieces-loosely-joined.html) and [this blog](http://www.offermann.us/2013/12/tiny-docker-pieces-loosely-joined.html), but not sure how to fit the pieces together.

In short, I would like to manage the oracle data in a data only Docker image, how to do it ?

Comment: are there any `VOLUME` instructions in the Dockerfile for `wnameless/xe-temp`?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stucK?

Comment: your link to the SO question points to the offermann-blog

Answer (score 5):

I've realized volumes mount for db data.
Here is my fork:

- Reduce size of image from 3.8G to 825Mb
- Database initialization moved out of the image build phase. Now database initializes at the containeer startup with no database files mounted
- media reuse support outside of container. Added graceful shutdown on containeer stop
- Removed sshd

You may check here:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sath89/oracle-xe-11g

https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-xe-11g

Answer (score 2):

I tried mapping the datafiles and fast recovery directories in my oracle xe container. However, I changed my mind after losing the files ... so you should be very careful about this approach and understand how docker manages those spaces under all operations.

I found, for example, that if you clean out old containers, the contents of the mapped directories will be deleted even if they are mapped to something outside the docker system area (/var/lib/docker).  You can avoid this by keeping containers and starting them up again. But, if you want to version and make a new image... you have to backup those files.

Oracle also id's the files themselves (checksum or inode # or something) and complains about them on startup.... I did not investigate the extent of that issue or even if there is indeed any issue there.

I've opted to not map any of those files/dirs and plan to use datapump or whatever to get the data out until I get a better handle on all that can happen.

So I update the data and version the image... pushing to to the repo for safe-keeping

Comment: Thanks. It seems I am unable to start an image with updated data after tagging. Do you just commit the container and version the image from it ?

Comment: Yes. And, I give it a tag that indicates it's special status.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
# Start data container
docker run -d -v /dbdata --name dbdata -it ubuntu

# Put oracale data in /dbdata some how

# Start container with stabase and look for data at /dbdata
docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db -it ubuntu
```

Comment: How would you handle the control.dbf files (which to my understanding will tell oracle where to look for dbf files)?  https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/ hardcodes it in the DockerFile.  I know how to do --volumes-from to store tablespaces there...but since control.dbf is stored in oracle container it seems that info will be lost upon a container restart.

Comment: Can they also not be mounted in from a volume? If not you can use the new exec feature in docker 1.3 to update them after a container comes up.